# How can I binding a listboxitem content in a muiltbinding?

Tags: wpf

I am doing my first project using wpf. I really need your help and suggestion. Thanks in advance.

I am building a screen, which has two listboxes A & B. Listbox A is binding to items load from database. listbox B is binding to a statics list. When user selects an item in listbox A, the associate item will be highlighted in listbox B. I am doing it by using MultiBinding in a listboxtitem. I'd like to pass selected data object and listboxitem content. The Convert() will take these two variables and check them. If match, it will return true to IsSelected property of item and highlight it. But it seems item content (statics string) can't be passed to converter(). What should I do?

see my xaml code:

```
             <ListBox Name="AbsenseCode" ItemsSource="{Binding absenseCodeItems}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="5" Margin="20,0,20,5" >
                    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                            <Setter Property="IsSelected">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource IsItemSelected}">
                                        <Binding ElementName="FilterListbox" Path="SelectedItem"/>
                                        <Binding Path="Content"/>
                                    </MultiBinding>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
              </ListBox>
```

when debugging, the second binging variable, content of item, is "{DependencyProperty.UnsetValue}".

Comment: What is the `Content` of your `ListBoxItem`? To me, it looks like it doesn't have any content in it. And we're talking about actual `Content` property of the `ListBoxItem` not a property in the `ViewModel`

Comment: It is a string, like "LB", "AF"... Even I use "ListBoxItem.Content", the same result.

Comment: instead of <Binding Path="Content" /> just do <Binding/> and then on the converter do ListBoxItem.Value or Text...don't know exactly...but it should work :)

Comment: Replacing <Binding Path="Content" /> with <Binding/>, run, got error: An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll Additional information: Two-way binding requires Path or XPath.

Comment: Oh, it works just add Mode=OneWay. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

this is a few months old, but I had a similar situation.

First, build a iMultiValueConveter that will compare two values and return the result to a string. "true" or "false" or "yes" or "no".

then in the XAML, define a style that can be triggered by the converter return. In this, ListBoxB has an ellipse where the fill will be green if the values match, red if they dont:

```
 <Window.Resources>
    <myNamespace:IsEqualConverter x:Key="IsEqualConverter" />
</Window.Resources>


<ListBox Name="ListBoxA" ItemsSource="{Binding}">

</ListBox>

<ListBox Name="ListBoxB" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <StackPanel>
            <StackPanel.Resources>
                <!-- style triggered by converter result -->
                <Style TargetType="Ellipse" x:Key="EllipseStyle">
                    <Setter Property="Fill" Value="#E5E5E5" />
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=result,Path=Text}" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Green" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=result,Path=Text}" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Red" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </StackPanel.Resources>
            <Ellipse Height="50" Width="50" Style="{StaticResoure EllipseStyle}" />
            <TextBlock x:Name="value0" Text="{Binding ElementName=ListBoxA,Path=SelectedItem.(Whatever),Mode=OneWay}" />
            <TextBlock x:Name="value1" Text="{Data Binding you want to compare to}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
            <TextBlock x:Name="result">
                <TextBlock.Text>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource IsEqualConverter}">
                        <Binding ElementName="value0" Path="Text" />
                        <Binding ElementName="value1" Path="Text" />
                    </MultiBinding>
                </TextBlock.Text>
            </TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```